# Best WordPress "contact us" plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

I've seen a few, and tried out [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/), which is pretty good but by default looks quite ugly.

I've also had a quick dig, and it looks hard to add some hooks for CSS. It also doesn't use the `label` element.

What is the best standards compliant easy skinnable contact Wordpress plugin in your experience?

### Update

I just found out how I can add my own `label` elements and get it to work with Contact Form 7.

Comment: @TiNS Maybe if I weren't a developer asking a developer related question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give these two alternatives a go or even create your own by posting to the page itself and using some custom code in your `functions.php` file.

- [cformsII](http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/)
- [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) (Premium Plugin)

I've used cformsII quite a bit and it comes with a library of skins, a click-to-build interface, and pre-built forms. It's got loads of options and is incredibly robust for a free plugin. Some other great features it has an auto responder and you can even have it post form data else where for further customization.

Answer (score 3):

[cform](http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/) is highly configurable and handle the customization of the css very well, right from the control panel or via ftp, whichever you like best.

**UPDATE**

We also use "[Fast And Secure Contact Form](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/si-contact-form/)" on our Wordpress MU network, and it works a treat.

Answer (score 1):

There's a new plugin called [Formidable](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/formidable/) I use and like better than others I've tried. Its drag-and-drop interface makes it so easy to use that I can let clients set up their own forms. The free version is sufficient for most needs, and if you're willing to upgrade to the paid version ($35 for a single install, $97 for infinite) you get reporting and a number of additional fields.

Comment: This is really cool! Thanks for posting this link, I'll be sure to check it out.